# .fmx Oracle Form automatization

Tags: windows, oracle, powershell, batch-file, oracleforms

I have a requirement and I dont know how to start?

My client has an Oracle Form (.fmx), when you open the .fmx file a dialog asking for username and password is open.

After inserting the username and password and pressing the Enter key a new form is open with an input asking for a specific ID.

What I need to do is to set up the username and password and hit enter automatically (using a script or something else)

how can I make that posible?

Note: what to do ?  type username and pass hit enter, next windows loads,set focus to the id input and type the id value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something to automatically fill in the fields and press a button. You can do this by using the Windows SendKeys API. There are various ways to do it with VBScript/PowerShell/AutoHotKey/AutoIt. Pick your poison.

I would probably do it in AutoHotKey because you can have it compile the script as an EXE to hide the username and password it enters.

You can have it search for the Window and focus it: 
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm

Then send keystrokes and button clicks to it: 
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

You can navigate the form by sending they Alt + hotkey of the form field. The hotkeys are normally underlined when you press the alt key on a form. So use this technique to focus the first field, and then either use it again or send the tab key to change focus to other fields. I would suggest avoiding use of tab and use the Alt + hotkey approach to select send input to all fields and to focus the form submission button.